# FragmentTabHost and custom tabs

Tags: android, tabs, android-support-library

I really need to access the images of a tab at runtime for scaling.
Therefore I made a custom tab layout with an imageview and a textview.

But if i want to add the custom tab to my tabhost I a  "did you forget to call 'public void setup(localactivitymanager activitygroup)'" exception.

Thx in advance for any solutions ;D

Ps. I cannot use

```
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("2").setIndicator(res.getString(R.string.tabname2), 
                                        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tabimage2));
```

tabHost.addTab(spec, FragmentTwo.class, null);

because i need to scale the image before adding.
Here is my class:

```
public class MyTabActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabmanager_layout);


     mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

     mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

     addCustomTab(getApplicationContext(),"Meldungen", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.messagewhite), NewsFragment.class, mTabHost);
     addCustomTab(getApplicationContext(),"Meldungen", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.messagewhite), NewsFragment.class, mTabHost);
     addCustomTab(getApplicationContext(),"Meldungen", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.messagewhite), NewsFragment.class, mTabHost);
     addCustomTab(getApplicationContext(),"Meldungen", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.messagewhite), NewsFragment.class, mTabHost);

     for(int i=0;i<mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
     {
         mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3b6c8d")); //unselected

     }

}

   private void addCustomTab(Context context,String labelId, Drawable drawable, Class<?> c, FragmentTabHost fth ) {
       View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tab_customtab, null);
       ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
       TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabtitle);

       image.setImageDrawable(drawable);
       text.setText(labelId);

       TabHost.TabSpec spec = fth.newTabSpec(labelId);
       Intent i = new Intent(this,c);
       spec.setContent(i);
       spec.setIndicator(view);
       fth.addTab(spec);


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `FragmentTabHost`'s custom `addTab()` which will also take your `Fragment` class as parameter.

Replace

```
TabHost.TabSpec spec = fth.newTabSpec(labelId);
Intent i = new Intent(this,c);
spec.setContent(i);
spec.setIndicator(view);
```

with

```
TabHost.TabSpec spec = fth.newTabSpec(labelId);
spec.setIndicator(view);
fth.addTab(spec, c, null);
```